# Preimage of a function in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I made this:

```
abbreviation "preimage f y ≡ { x . f x = y }"
```

Isn't there a built-in definition I could be using instead? How would I find that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f -` {a}
```

aka

```
vimage f {a}
```

I found by searching for theorems with the name image in it and hoping to find the right one with the symbol:

```
find_theorems name:image
```

I was lucky enough that it appeared in the first theorems... In general, a better approach is have an idea of the type and use find_consts:

```
find_consts "('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ 'b set ⇒ 'a set"
```